# Tensorflow: why is zip() function used in the steps involving applying the gradients?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am working through Assignment 6 of the Udacity Deep Learning course. I am unsure why the zip() function is used in these steps to apply the gradients.

Here is the relevant code:

```
# define the loss function
logits = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(tf.concat(0, outputs), w, b) 
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, tf.concat(0, train_labels)))

# Optimizer.

global_step = tf.Variable(0)
#staircase=True means that the learning_rate updates at discrete time steps
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(10.0, global_step, 5000, 0.1, staircase=True)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)

gradients, v = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.25)
optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, v), global_step=global_step)
```

What is the purpose of applying the `zip()` function?

Why is `gradients` and `v` stored that way? I thought `zip(*iterable)` returned just one zip object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know Tensorflow, but presumably `optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)` yields (gradient, value) tuples.

```
gradients, v = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
```

performs a *transposition*, creating a list of gradients and a list of values.

```
gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.25)
```

then clips the gradients, and

```
optimizer = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, v), global_step=global_step)
```

re-zips the gradient and value lists back into an iterable of (gradient, value) tuples which is then passed to the `optimizer.apply_gradients` method.